# How to check in Django if the date was yesterday

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates, compare

I want to compare some date fields on the db and check if they are old or they were submited today , i got this code

```
        {% if accounts.date.day == 13 %}
            {{ accounts.name }}
        {% endif %}
```

But i think this works on the day 13 of every motnh , and i dont want to only check if its day 13 i want to check if it wasnt today

I tried to do

```
        {% if accounts.date.day < today %}
            {{ accounts.name }}
        {% endif %}
```

And in the views

```
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
```

But it doesnt work either

Comment: Notice that you are comparing integer with date, not datetime with datetime

Comment: Not when i use the today variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if accounts.date is datetime
try this

```
{% if accounts.date < today %}
   {{ accounts.name }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That doesnt returns anything , in all cases

Comment: and accounts.date.day < today.day

Comment: Yes , but i have the same problem as before , i dont know if maybe i am at day 5th and the account date is 5th of the month before , will it count as true ? cause they have the same day

Comment: with this code will count as false this is why you must compare 2 datetime object,see this answers may  help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django

Comment: @Maks Yes, `date(2015, 6, 20) < date(2015, 7, 20)` is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

```
today = datetime.date.today()  
if (today - accounts.date).days == 1:
    print "%s is yesterday!"%accounts.date
```

maybe??

this assumes that `accounts.date` is an instance of `datetime.date`

```
if {% if (today.date - accounts.date).days == 1 %}
```

might work in the template ... or you could create a filter (thats what I would do

```
def isYesterday(a_date):
    return (datetime.date.today()-a_date).days == 1
```

then just do

```
{% if accounts.date | isYesterday %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in the template ? or do i have to do it on the urls.py or other .py file by force ?

Comment: No, you either need to create a templatetag like the isYesterday shown above or do this on the Account model or do it in the view logic