# Django cant do datetime comparision

Tags: python, django

I want to compare two datetimes. The problem is that I always get False. For example: validity_date = Jan. 31, 2016, 12:43 a.m, actual_time = Jan. 31, 2016, 2:40 p.m. gives False, validity_date = Feb. 12, 2016, 4:11 p.m., actual_time = Jan. 31, 2016, 2:40 p.m. gives False too. Thanks

```
#models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  validity_date = models.DateTimeField()

#views.py
def SomeView(request):
    model_list = SomeModel.objects.all()
    actual_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    context = {
        'model_list': model_list,
        'actual_time': actual_time,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/sometemplate.html', context)

#in template
{% if model_list %}
  {% for somemodel in model_list %}  
    {% if somemodel.validity_date >= actual_time %}
      <td>True</td>
    {% else %}
      <td>False</td>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement it as a model property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3798865/771848?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead of `datetime.datetime.now`, since this will give you timezone aware datetime. I think the comparison probably fails because you are comparing different types. Since it happens in a template, there's no error message.

Comment: django.utils.timezone.now helped, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably comparing with a timezone aware datetime. Use `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`

```
>>> import django, datetime

>>> django.utils.timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 15, 6, 35, 471795, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 16, 6, 43, 377016)

>>> datetime.datetime.now() > django.utils.timezone.now()
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```