# Django - Checking datetime in an 'if' statement

Tags: python, django

I have a model very imaginatively called '`model`' which has a field '`datefinish`' in it; users can input a date here in the format MM/DD/YYYY. In my template I need some text displayed when said model has a `datefinish` (date) that is equal to the current day.

HTML:

```
{% if model.datefinish == datetime.today %}
   <h5>It ends today</h5>
{% else %}
   <h5>It does not end today</h5>
{% endif %}
```

How might one achieve this?
I'm using Django 1.10...thanks!

Comment: Your title is very peculiar: you are definitely not "setting" an `if` statement equal to something.

Comment: @khelwood Apologies, not sure how else to word it - any recommendations?

Comment: Seems more like you are *checking* a datetime in an `if` statement.

Comment: @khelwood Changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The model option as per Daniel's suggestion, which I prefer as then you have it always available whenever you load that model

in the mode:

```
@property
def is_today(self):
  return self.datefinish == datetime.today().date()
```

this assumes that the 'datefinish' is a DateField, not a DateTimeField, for DateTimeField you would do `self.datefinish.date() == ...`

you can also see if its within a range, i.e.

```
return self.start_date <= datetime.today().date() <= self.end_date
```

if you have two dates in a model.

or create a template tag like:

```
@register.filter
def is_today(dt):
  if isinstance(dt, datetime):
    return dt.date() == datetime.today().date():
  if isinstance(dt, date):
    return dt == datetime.today().date():
```

then in the template you can do

```
{% if model.datetime_field|is_today %}
```

The filter can handle DateField and DateTimeField

Comment: +1 but this brings up 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date' error...even though it's a DateTimeField - any ideas?

Comment: could fix my code to test for NoneType, you likely have a datetimefield set to null in the database.

Comment: in other words: my code above assumes that you are always passing a valid object

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the template. Write a method on the model - called for example `finishes_today` - that does this check and returns a boolean, and call that in the template.

Comment: or add a templatetag

Comment: @bodolsog suggestion is also good if you often want to check this on multiple models

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid overloading templates with logic and put this check into the view (or as a model property as suggested by Daniel):

```
is_today = model.datefinish == datetime.today()

return render_to_response('template.html', {'is_today': is_today})
```

Then, in your template simply check the variable passed in the context:

```
{% if is_today %}
   <h5>It ends today</h5>
{% else %}
   <h5>It does not end today</h5>
{% endif %}
```

There is also [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959070/771848), but it does look a bit overly complicated.