# How to compare now and datetime field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

If i want to apply check like this in views.py:

```
now=timezone.now()
if now <= arrival:
        messages.error(request, 'Please enter valid Time')
        return redirect('add_schedule') 

where arrival is datetime field in models.py
```

It gives error of '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str', How can i apply this check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare dates in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there are multiple ways for this.

1- the best and easiest one is to use datetime function __ gt __() which means "**G**reater **T**han":

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if arrival.__gt__(now):
    messages.error(request, 'Please enter valid Time')
    return redirect('add_schedule')
```

2- but alternatively you can use timestamps to compare two dates:

```
currentTimestamp = now.timestamp()
arrivalTimestamp = arrival.timestamp()
if arrivalTimestamp > currentTimestamp :
    messages.error(request, 'Please enter valid Time')
    return redirect('add_schedule')
```

**Note**: the second way use more ram and possibly have less speed