# django - template IF tag - how to do IF variable <= current date

Tags: django, templatetags

In my models.py I have a `end_date` variable. In my template, I'd like to show certain stuff only if that `end_date` is passed. Is there a way to do that in the template?

```
{% if end_date <= now %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

That doesn't work... Any pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: it does answer my question - thanks!

Comment: the answer to the question can be found in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django-templates