# Django template, how can i use if condition with using {% now 'F jS Y' %}

Tags: django, django-templates

this is my template, how can i compare the date now with my myaccount.modifyDate ?

```
<input   name="temperature" value="{% if {% now 'F jS Y' %} >= myaccount.modifyDate   %} 0.0 {% else %} {{myaccount.bodyTemperature}} {% endif %}" readonly></td>
```

Update i tried this also

```
<input   name="temperature" value="{% if ( {% now 'F jS Y' %} ) >= myaccount.modifyDate   %} 0.0 {% else %} {{myaccount.bodyTemperature}} {% endif %}" readonly></td>
```

and the error is

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(' from '('
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your models

```
from datetime import date
@property
    def is_past_due(self):
        return date.today() > self.modifyDate
    class Meta:
```

and do this in your html

```
<input   name="temperature" value="{% if myaccount.is_past_due  %} 0.0  {% else %}  {{myaccount.bodyTemperature}} {% endif %}" readonly>
```

for more information click this [How to compare dates in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% now 'F jS Y' as nowdate %}
{% if nowdate == "November 9th 2023" %}
```

Works for me in Django v3.9