# How to check if a date is still less than 5 days in django query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to check if the date an order was created is still less than 5 days, then i want to display a `New Order` Text.

This is how i have tried doing this

```
def vendor_orders(request):
    five_days = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5)
    new_orders = CartOrder.objects.filter(payment_status="paid", date__lte=five_days).order_by("-id")
```

This is returning all the orders in the database that the date is less than 5 days, which means all orders  both old and new are being returned and this is not what i am expecting.
If i manually create an order and set the date manually to some date in the future e.g July or August, it does not return that order.

Please how can i go about this logic? all i want to do is display an order as new orders if the date which the order was created is not yet older than 5 days.

## Template Update

i want to check if the order is a new order then i display a **new** badge

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def vendor_orders(request):
    five_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5) # this is 5 days ago
    new_order = CartOrder.objects.filter(payment_status="paid", vendor=request.user.vendor, date__gte=five_days).order_by("-id")

    order = CartOrder.objects.filter(payment_status="paid", vendor=request.user.vendor).order_by("-id")
    
    context = {
        "order":order,
        "five_days":five_days,
        "new_order":new_order,
    } 
    return render(request, "vendor/vendor-order.html", context)
```

```
{% for o in order %}
<tr>
   <th scope="row">#{{o.oid}} <span class="badge">{% if o.date > five_days %}New{% endif %}</span></th>
   <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'vendor:order-detail' o.oid %}" class="btn btn-primary">View Order</a></th>
   <td>{{o.date}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you want.

```
def vendor_orders(request):
    five_days = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=5) #5 days ago
    
    #orders with a date greater than the date 5 days ago
    new_orders = CartOrder.objects.filter(payment_status="paid", date__gte=five_days).order_by("-id")
```

Comment: Yes, that is it. ,Please help me look at this conditional statement i wrote in the template for the same logic, `{% if o.date > five_days %}New{% endif %}` it seems not to be working. I have updated the question with my updated view and template  -

Comment: Then why did you need to do a query for new orders if you want to do the filtering in the template anyway?

Comment: that is because i need to count how many new orders and also display the result in another section in the template like this `Total New Orders - {{ new_orders.count }}`

Comment: Combining my answer with the answers in this thread should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django-templates